# Creating a 3D graph out of 3 lists that contain recurring values

Tags: python-3.x, list, matplotlib, graph, 3d

I'm new to python.
I'm working on a machine learning problem in which I value my models by their accuracy given a theta (learning rate) and a number of epochs.
How can I create a clear 3D graph that will represent a 2 argument function like the following:
f(theta, num of epochs) = accuracy.
I want to clarify that each theta runs through all number of epochs therefore
for example if:
theta values = 0.1, 1
epoch values = 5, 10, 15
then I will value the accuracy of the cartesian product of theta values and
epoch values and then I need to plot it.

Here is an example for such lists:

[1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002]

[5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 160, 160, 160, 160, 320, 320, 320, 320]

[0.6576355636979362, 0.6494099087220626, 0.6488214366675455, 0.6494219372389003, 0.6606834048104814, 0.6515514473544203, 0.648811721327023, 0.6454677936461672, 0.6567195458772259, 0.6561162694942934, 0.6533700665732143, 0.6503374924243476, 0.6558169444791421, 0.6536837332815182, 0.6479040309410463, 0.6427229786308771, 0.6570221093392181, 0.6497263512419444, 0.652764477013967, 0.6536897475399369, 0.6567246348651186, 0.6485054567829269, 0.6479012551294685, 0.6442506002692537, 0.6625038745703276, 0.6512535102450578, 0.6509463204304359, 0.6494219372389003]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question; nevertheless, here's an example of how to plot the three lists you've given in 3D:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x=np.array([1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002, 1, 0.1, 0.010000000000000002, 0.0010000000000000002])

y=np.array([5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 160, 160, 160, 160, 320, 320, 320, 320])

z=np.array([0.6576355636979362, 0.6494099087220626, 0.6488214366675455, 0.6494219372389003, 0.6606834048104814, 0.6515514473544203, 0.648811721327023, 0.6454677936461672, 0.6567195458772259, 0.6561162694942934, 0.6533700665732143, 0.6503374924243476, 0.6558169444791421, 0.6536837332815182, 0.6479040309410463, 0.6427229786308771, 0.6570221093392181, 0.6497263512419444, 0.652764477013967, 0.6536897475399369, 0.6567246348651186, 0.6485054567829269, 0.6479012551294685, 0.6442506002692537, 0.6625038745703276, 0.6512535102450578, 0.6509463204304359, 0.6494219372389003])

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```